# CANON printer setup with no driver openSUSE

Tags: opensuse, printer

I just bought a new printer/scanner combo and am attempting to set it up with my pc which runs openSUSE 13.1.

I went to yast-> hardware-> printers and followed the prompts however, although my printer was detected there were no found drivers.

So when I go to print the computer does not acknowledge my printer.

I went to the canon website, and it states there are no linux drivers for the printer, which is the canon pixma mx459.

any suggestions?

Comment: http://linux.wikia.com/wiki/Getting_Canon_PIXMA_to_work_on_Linux shows Ubuntu but might be adaptable to suse

Comment: That thread utilizes available drivers; there are no drivers I have been able to find for this model.

Comment: Correct, you'll have to then find out what was used to build those packages and install it manually. Printers are notoriously a pain in the butt on Linux, I'll often find ones that work first, and then purchase from that list vs. just getting a random printer.

Comment: Did you try [here](http://www.canon-europe.com/For_Home/Product_Finder/Printers/Inkjet/Home-Office-Printers/index.aspx)? I've found better support for Linux on the European side of Canon...