# Canon MF743Cdw on Linux without drivers?

Tags: linux, printing, printer, canon

I hate printers. I have terrible luck with them. I just had a Brother HL-3180cdw die on me (right after the warranty expired, of course) in a way that will cost more to fix than the printer cost. That had (proprietary) drivers which worked fine with Fedora — not a great experience, but, eh.

I know Canon is *not* very Linux friendly, but I'm nonetheless tempted by their three-year warranty. Specifically, I'm looking at the [MF743Cdw](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/printers/color-laser/color-imageclass-mf743cdw).

Does anyone have experience using this under Linux *without* installing drivers? That is, using network printing and standard Postcript or PCL or whatever?

What about scanning? Any chance of that working without a driver? (If not, can that be at least controlled directly via the panel on the printer and *sent* to a Linux-based network share? The Brother printer *seemed* like it would be able to do this but it didn't actually work.)

I am using Fedora Workstation (although I don't think that should matter much in this case). I found [CANON printer setup with no driver openSUSE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146031/canon-printer-setup-with-no-driver-opensuse), but note that that's talking about a printer in the "PIXMA" line — I expect laser printers to be more likely to work with Postscript.

Does anyone have experience with this printer in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 years too late to be useful to Matt, but for posterity's sake, the Canon MF743Cdw does work out of the box for both network (wired or wireless) printing and scanning on Fedora Workstation.

For OpenSUSE based distros like Tumbleweed, the firewall is enabled by default and set to a public zone.  To get Yast to find the printer, you'll need to adjust your firewall settings, e.g. change your zone to home.  OpenSUSE also doesn't include sane-airscan which means your scanning app won't find the MF743Cdw.  There are official OpenSUSE packages built on OBS linked from the sane-airscan GitHub page here: https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan.

Answer (score 0):

I've investigated this a bit. I email'd ThinkPenguin whom I love because they know how to figure out and go through and vet hardware before they sell it and the company said that there is one all-in-one B&W Canon laser printer that was properly supported using only free software. There was possibly a 2nd similar model. There is possibly one color laser all-in-one model in the $900-1000 range although that hasn't been confirmed. The MF644Cdw does not have postscript/PCL or any standard languages supported sadly. It might be possible to scan from what I'm reading.